# Changing FusionTablesLayerOptions Style Options

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

How does one change the style of a FusionLayer object?

I am trying to create a onClick event that will highlight the state that was clicked on. In order to do this, I want the object strokeOpacity to increase and the strokeColor to change to red.

If the object were a polygon, I could do this:

```
var red = "#FF0000"; //red
function LoadStates() {
    var points = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(34.984, -85.605),   
    new google.maps.LatLng(32.864, -85.184) 

    //...etc  
    ];


    var alabama = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: points,
        strokeColor: outlineColor,
        strokeOpacity: 0,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: invisColor,
        fillOpacity: 0
    });

    //add event listeners to polygon, then add polygon to map
    google.maps.event.addListener(alabama, 'mouseover', function () {
        alabama.setOptions({ strokeColor: red });
        alabama.setOptions({ strokeOpacity: 1 });
    });

   google.maps.event.addListener(alabama, 'mouseout', function () {
        alabama.setOptions({ strokeOpacity: 0 });
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(alabama, 'click', function () {
        document.getElementById("StateName").innerHTML = "Alabama"; extend();
    });
    alabama.setMap(map);

}
```

Since the object is a polygon, I can simply use .setOptions to change the strokeColor and Opacity.

How can I change the polygon options for a FusionLayers object created from a kml file?

The "arizona" boundary file.

```
function LoadAZ() {
    arizona = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
        suppressInfoWindows: false,

        query: {
            select: 'col4',
            from: '210217',
            where: "col3 <= 'B' "
        },

        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                strokeColor: outlineColor,
                strokeOpacity: 0.01,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: invisColor,
                fillOpacity: .01
            }
```

The styles options here will change. How can I change the options on an event?
I want to do something like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(arizona, 'mouseover', function () {
        arizona.setOptions({ strokeOpacity: 1 });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setOptions` method to change it directly.

```
var selectedOptions = {
        styles: [{
            polygonOptions: {
                strokeColor: red,
                strokeOpacity: 1,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: invisColor,
                fillOpacity: .01
            }

        }]
    }

google.maps.event.addListener(arizona, 'click', function (clickEvent) {
        document.getElementById("StateName").innerHTML = "Arizona"; extend();
        arizona.setOptions(selectedOptions);
    });
```

This will change the polygonOptions for the kml file directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_mouseover.html) that changes the style of polygons in a FusionTable using the google visualization API to create native v3 polygons from data stored in the table and add mouseover/out events to them.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you can't handle the `mouseover` of a FusionTablesLayer, the only supported event is `click` (correct me if I'm wrong).

However: there is a library called [Fusion Tips](http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/examples.html), that enables the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event for FusionTablesLayer. Check [this good blog post](http://csessig.wordpress.com/2012/02/07/multiple-layers-and-rollover-effects-for-fusion-table-maps/) about how to use the library.